# How to convert the content of email message in html format in JSP, Servlet aplication?

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, java-web-start

I'm working in a project that necessite send email. Emails are already being sent, but I need to implement a more professional format and, from what I've researched, I can implement an HTML format to email. This is necessary because I have to put information related to the project company (image 
corporate). I tried using msg.SendContent but it didn't work for me. I hope you can guide me.

I'm using NetBeans with the `javax.mail` library:

```
public class EmailServicio {

    public static void enviarEmail(String host, String port,
            final String user, final String pass, String destinatario,
            String asunto, String mensaje) throws AddressException,
            MessagingException {

        // sets SMTP server properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        // creates a new session with an authenticator
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);
            }
        };

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

        // creates a new e-mail message
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = {new InternetAddress(destinatario)};
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
        msg.setSubject(asunto);
        msg.setContent("<h1>Maipo Grande, lider en exportación</h1>", "text/html");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText(mensaje);

        // sends the e-mail
        Transport.send(msg);
    }
}
```

**Servlet Code:**

```
public class ServletContacto extends HttpServlet {

    private String host;
    private String port;
    private String user;
    private String pass;

    public void init() {
        // reads SMTP server setting from web.xml file
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        host = context.getInitParameter("host");
        port = context.getInitParameter("port");
        user = context.getInitParameter("user");
        pass = context.getInitParameter("pass");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        UsuarioServicio usua = new UsuarioServicio();
        String url = request.getRequestURI();

        if ("/maipoGrande/Contacto".equals(url)) {
            request.setAttribute("titulo", "Formulario Contacto");
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            if (session.getAttribute("usuario") == null) {
                response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/Login");
            } else {
                getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/contacto.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        String url = request.getRequestURI();
        if ("/maipoGrande/Contacto".equals(url)) {
            String destinatario = "atencion.maipogrande@gmail.com";
            String asunto = request.getParameter("txtAsunto");
            String mensaje = request.getParameter("txtMensaje");
            String mensajeRespuesta = "";
            try {
                EmailServicio.enviarEmail(host, port, user, pass, destinatario, asunto,
                        mensaje);
                mensajeRespuesta = "Su correo fue enviado exitosamente";
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                mensajeRespuesta = "Se ha encontrado un error: " + ex.getMessage();
            } finally {
                request.setAttribute("Mensaje", mensajeRespuesta);
                getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/resultado.jsp").forward(
                        request, response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that the h1 (test) is displayed in the message sent.

Comment: [1] Is you code compiling? The second parameter to `PasswordAuthentication` should be`char[] password` but you are passing the `String` variable `pass`. [2] Edit your post to specify a clear question. As it stands it hard to work out exactly what your problem is.

Comment: The code compiles, what happens is that I want to send an email with html format. You can see that in class "EmailServicio" on the line msg.setContent("<h1>Maipo Grande, lider en exportación</h1>", "text/html"); I'm trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you haven't stated exactly what your problem is, it may be that you are calling `msg.setText(mensaje);` after calling `msg.setContent("<h1>Maipo Grande, lider en exportación</h1>", "text/html");`.

Your call to `msg.setContent()` will set the MIME type to **"text/html"**, which is what you want. But the subsequent call to `msg.setText()` will reset the MIME type to **"text/plain"**, which is not what you want when sending an HTML email..

The solution is simply to remove the call to `msg.setText()`. Then you will be sending an HTML email. Of course you will also need to amend the content of the message  passed to `msg.setContent()` for your application's email, but that is just an implementation detail.

See [the Javadoc for the interface `javax.mail.Part`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Part.html), which is implemented by class `javax.mail.Message`, for more information on `setContent()` and `setText()`.

One other related point is that it looks like your `EmailServicio.enviarEmail()` method is almost a direct copy of the `main()` method of class `SendHTMLEmail` in the tutorial "[JavaMail API - Sending an HTML Email](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_html_in_email.htm)", apart from the call to `setText()` that you added.

It's worth verifying that you can successfully run your implementation of their simple Java application first. It is much easier to debug a Java application than a servlet if there are any issues to be resolved. Once you have the HTML email application working you can then port your working code over to the web application.